# Remove <div> after user's action inside <iframe>

Tags: jquery, iframe, stripe-payments

I have a payment form which is an `<iframe>` from a third party and a `<div>` after it. Once the user completes the payment, I want to remove this div.

```
<iframe id="payment-form"> </iframe>
<div class="to-disappear"></div>

<script language="javascript">
  var iframe = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  iframe.src = 'https:somelink.com';
</script>
```

I saw many people suggesting `.load(function()` but this is not the case. I need to remove `.to-disappear` after the payment, not the initial loading. Once the payment has been successful, I receive a token from Stripe, maybe that could be useful.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you will see stripe js you are using to generate token you will see this method stripeResponseHandler in this when script is appending token to your form you can write code to hide

```
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
                    if (response.error) {
                        // re-enable the submit button
                        $('.submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");
                        // show the errors on the form
                        $(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
                    } else {
                        var form$ = $("#payment-form");
                        // token contains id, last4, and card type
                        var token = response['id'];
                        // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                        form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");
                        // and submit
                        form$.get(0).submit();
                    }
                }
```